# Obtaining underlying nutrition data from "NutritionLabel"

Tags: entity

I would like to extract the underlying nutritional data contained in "NutritionLabel" output from Wolfram Alpha for *all* of the "Vegetables" defined in the "BasicFoodGroup" Entity

```
In[34]:= EntityList["BasicFoodGroup"]

Out[34]= {Entity["BasicFoodGroup", "Dairy"], 
 Entity["BasicFoodGroup", "Fruits"], 
 Entity["BasicFoodGroup", "Grains"], 
 Entity["BasicFoodGroup", "ProteinFoods"], 
 Entity["BasicFoodGroup", "Vegetables"]}
```

I've been going round and round on this without much luck. Any suggestions would be most welcomed!

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: You might want to systematically inspect the result of e.g. `CanonicalName /@ EntityProperties[Entity["Food", "Celery::33w36"]]`. In particular, look at the `"*DailyValuePercent"` and `"*ContentPerServing"` properties.

Comment: Getting the list of vegetable entities consistently times our for me. `Entity["BasicFoodGroup", "Vegetables"]["Foods"]`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi. I had also tried the approach you suggest but it timed out for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, `Entity["BasicFoodGroup", "Vegetables"]["Foods"]` times out. I tried it in the Wolfram Cloud and it timed out there too. It works for dairy.

```
dairyFoods = Entity["BasicFoodGroup", "Dairy"]["Foods"];
```

Generate list of nutrition related properties

```
contentPerServingProperties = Entity["Food"]["Properties"] // 
  Select[StringMatchQ[CanonicalName[#], "*PerServing"] &];

dailyValuePercentProperties = Entity["Food"]["Properties"] // 
  Select[StringMatchQ[CanonicalName[#], "*DailyValuePercent"] &];

servingSizeProperties = {
   EntityProperty["Food", "DefaultItemSizeMass"],
   EntityProperty["Food", "DefaultServingSizeMass"],
   EntityProperty["Food", "DefaultServingSizeVolume"]};

nutritionProperties = Join[servingSizeProperties, contentPerServingProperties, dailyValuePercentProperties];
```

Generate `Association` from food to nutrition properties for the first 10 dairy foods.

```
AssociationMap[
  EntityValue[#, nutritionProperties, "PropertyAssociation"] & /* DeleteMissing /* DeleteCases[{}],
  dairyFoods[[1 ;; 10]]]
```